# How to show a sequence of random variables is not uniformly tight

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

If $X_{n}\sim N(n,1)$, then how to show $X_{n} \neq O_{p}(1)$?

Note: Here I define $X_{n} = O_{p}(1)$ to mean:

For every $\epsilon$, there is a $M$ s.t. $\sup P(|X_{n}|>M)<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $X_n \sim N(n,1)$, we have $\mathbb{P}(X_n >n) = \frac{1}{2}$. In particular, $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > n) \geq \mathbb{P}(X_n>n) = \frac{1}{2}.$$ Consequently, if $\epsilon \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ then there cannot exist $M>0$ such that

$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > M) < \epsilon.$$

Comment: quick follow up question: did we use the condition that the var = 1 in this proof?

Comment: @Nemandbun No, we didn't; the reasoning works more generally for $X_n \sim N(n,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2>0$.